# How to correctly call a function in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am creating a script using psycopg2 that does a number of DB functions. So far I've had no issues with selects, inserts, etc. but I am having an issue when calling a function.

The function is quite simple:

```
create or replace function create_sample(_m_id int) returns bigint as
$$
DECLARE
count bigint;
BEGIN
    perform update_function(_m_id,true);
    select count(*) from table_1 where m_id = _m_id into count;
    return count;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

From the python script, I am calling this as follows:

```
def run_sample(m_id):
    cur.callproc("create_sample", [m_id,])
    print(cur.fetchone())
    if debug:
        print(cur.query)
    SQL = "SELECT count(*) from table_1 where m_id = %s;"
    cur.execute(SQL, [m_id])
    if debug:
        print(cur.query)
    results_1 = cur.fetchone()[0]
    print(results_1)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

When I original call the function, a value of 0 is returned as opposed to the of count (`update_function` inserts rows into `table_1`, so I'm expecting the number of rows to be returned).

Then when I check again by running a select, the value is still 0.

At the end of the script, everything is committed and I can see that everything has 'worked' except the function call.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: It is not related to python but to postgresql. Please change question  tags

Comment: Ok thanks, I figured as the function definitely works when tested in a psql terminal that it must be a python issue

Comment: If `update_function` 'writes' something, you probably just forgot to `commit()` ? `create_sample` works fine for me, leaving `perform update_function(_m_id,true);` out.

Comment: I've edited the question now but in my code I had a commit outside the method already. Really not sure what the issue is as there are other things in the script being committed successfully before this point. Maybe ```update_function``` is unable to be called in this way

Answer (score 0):

I've never used callproc but I believe your issue is this:

> This function is, at present, not DBAPI-compliant. The return value is supposed to consist of the sequence of parameters with modified output and input/output parameters. In future versions, the DBAPI-compliant return value may be implemented, but for now the function returns None.
>
> The procedure may provide a result set as output. This is then made available through the standard `fetch*()` methods.

Your procedure is not returning a *resultset*, I believe that'd imply returning a `refcursor` whereas you're just returning a `bigint`.